# Can I securely implement cookieless "keep me signed in" using localstorage in a mobile app?

Tags: security, authentication, hash, local-storage, cookieless

I don't want users to have to enter their passwords each time, and I don't want to store the passwords locally.  When the user first sends me their username and password, I'm planning to send back some hashed version of their password (hash of pasword+salt), which will be put into localstorage to be used to authorize subsequent calls to our web services.

I'm aware that if my localstorage is compromised (e.g. stolen phone), the thief will be able to steal the token and make web service calls as the user, but at least they won't have the user's password.

Are there other vulnerabilities that I'm overlooking?  Is there a reason to put it in a cookie instead of localstorage?

Comment: Both cookie and localstorage are just places to hold your information. They are almost equal in security level (well, you can obfuscate localstorage).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things to consider.  You should use SSL to protect against eavesdropping.  Otherwise any peer (someone else at the same insecure WiFi spot as your user) may be able to record your hashed password and replay requests with it.  Also, the strength of the hashing algorithm is important.  With a known username and a weak password it may be possible to generate a table of potential hashes and test that against the known hash (if the attacker manages to compromise the hash).

Regarding the difference between this and cookies, it's pretty simple.  Cookies are usually randomly generated by the Server and aren't derived from the password at all.  Other than that, cookies are pretty much a shortcut to what you're talking about.  Whether you save it in your own storage within your app or to the HTTP library's built-in cookie handler, doesn't really matter.  As long as you make sure to use SSL to protect against the eavesdropping/replay attack you should be pretty safe.

Also, I would recommend that you use a server generated hash so that you take the user password out of the equation completely.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Yes, all traffic will be over SSL, and the server is definitely the one doing the hashing.  So you're saying that having the token in localstore is as secure as having it in a cookie?

Comment: Yes, the cookie is just a shortcut for that.  All it does is save something from the server and reuse it on all further communication with that server.

Comment: Ok, thank you.  :)  I'm going to wait a bit and see if anyone can think of a disadvantage or weakness, and then mark your response as the answer.